# What is the easiest way to process JSON file in .NET v4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

As in title, I have to process JSON file using platform .NET 4.0.
I tried to use System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json but
VSC complains about .NET framework versioning...

```
error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targe 
ting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Pac 
ks at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Comment: You should be able to use Newtonsoft.Json without problems.

Comment: ^^ Even the newest version seems compatible: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: Can you post that "complaint" ? And "VSC" refers to "Visual Studio Code", I guess?

Comment: @Fildor I updated my question about that complaint. Yes, I'm using Visual Studio Code together with MSBuild

Comment: That error message indicates, you haven't installed the .NET Framework 4.0 SDK ??

Comment: .NET 4.0 SDK is not available anymore, at least I didn't find anything for windows 10 and newer